# Can not access a closed stream Itext7

Tags: itext7

I am using itext7 for PDF manipulation. I am trying to fill form fields by field.setValue method. My _Reader object is filled at constructor level and is used on Adding and Getting form fields. But on Saving form field value, on closing PdfDocument object following exception is caught:

```
at System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed()
at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at iText.IO.Source.OutputStream`1.Write(Byte[] b, Int32 off, Int32 len)
at iText.IO.Source.OutputStream`1.WriteInteger(Int32 value)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter.WriteToBody(PdfObject pdfObj)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter.FlushObject(PdfObject pdfObject, Boolean 
canBeInObjStm)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument.FlushObject(PdfObject pdfObject, Boolean 
canBeInObjStm)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfObject.Flush(Boolean canBeInObjStm)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfPage.Flush(Boolean flushResourcesContentStreams)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfPage.Flush()
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument.Close()
```

Code snippet is as following:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(_Reader, new PdfWriter(memoryStream));
            PdfAcroForm Form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(document, true);
            foreach (PDFField Field in PDFFields)
            {
                PdfFormField formField = Form.GetField(Field.Name);

                switch (Field.Type)
                {
                    case PDF_FIELD_TYPE.TEXTBOX:
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Field.Value))
                            formField.SetValue(Field.Value);
                        else
                            formField.SetValue(string.Empty);
                        break;
                }
            }
            document.Close();
            byte[] PDFBytes = ((MemoryStream)memoryStream).ToArray();
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I don't see anything closing the memory stream before the `document.Close()`. Are you sure you have not forgotten something relevant in your code snippet?

Comment: Yes I have added all the code here. The reader object is initialized in the constructor as mentioned above